# Compare two MYSQL tables and return missing dates and group by column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, mysql-workbench

I have two tables. I want to compare table A with B and get the missing date from with name of the user.

**TABLE A**

```
|----|----------|------------|
| 1  | king     | 2020-08-01 |
| 2  | king     | 2020-08-02 |
| 3  | queen    | 2020-08-01 |
| 4  | queen    | 2020-08-02 |
| 5  | rook     | 2020-08-03 |
| 6  | bishop   | 2020-08-01 |
| 7  | bishop   | 2020-08-01 |
| 8  | queen    | 2020-08-03 |
```

**TABLE B**

```
| id | working_date |
|----|--------------|
| 1  | 2020-08-01   |
| 2  | 2020-08-02   |
| 3  | 2020-08-03   |
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
| name   | missing_date |
|--------|--------------|
| king   | 2020-08-03   |
| rook   | 2020-08-01   |
| rook   | 2020-08-02   |
| bishop | 2020-08-02   |
| bishop | 2020-08-03   |
```

*Also, Along with it can I get the **count** of the missing dates for each user if possible?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cross join Table B to the distinct names of Table A and then left join Table A to filter out the matching rows:

```
select n.name, b.working_date missing_date 
from TableB b
cross join (select distinct name from TableA) n
left join TableA a on a.name = n.name and a.working_date = b.working_date
where a.id is null
```

If you want to count the missing_dates use the same query and group by name:

```
select n.name, count(*) missing_dates 
from TableB b
cross join (select distinct name from TableA) n
left join TableA a on a.name = n.name and a.working_date = b.working_date
where a.id is null
group by n.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=74696098bc9446707592eb0ed0044664).
Results:

```
> name   | missing_date
> :----- | :-----------
> king   | 2020-08-03  
> rook   | 2020-08-01  
> rook   | 2020-08-02  
> bishop | 2020-08-02  
> bishop | 2020-08-03
```

and:

```
> name   | missing_dates
> :----- | ------------:
> bishop |             2
> king   |             1
> rook   |             2
```

Comment: Thanks  :) , This was very helpful. But can i get both the queries as single table?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Then you can't use window functions which were introduced in version 8.0 So you can get what you want only if you join these 2 queries: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6f66d0b039c7244244915db3882e456d

Comment: For MySql 8.0 the solution is easy: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97eeefcd29bcbe8b79df67392a3b483c

Answer (score 0):

Getting distinct user names from Table A and joining it with Table B you can create all working date variations of the users. Then with not exists you can list missing dates:

```
SELECT A1.name, B.working_date
FROM B JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT name
   FROM A) A1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM A
  WHERE A.name = A1.name
    and A.working_date = B.working_date
)
```

For your last question finding missing counts you can use the below query:

```
SELECT S.name, COUNT(1) AS 'MissingDatesCount'
FROM (
    SELECT A1.name, B.working_date
    FROM B JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT name
       FROM A) A1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM A
      WHERE A.name = A1.name
        and A.working_date = B.working_date
    )
) S
GROUP BY S.name
```

Go to the [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fd9d3/9)

Comment: An INNER join without an ON clause is a CROSS join.

Comment: @forpas thanks for the explanation, that is what actually aimed.